# $\ast$-preserving homomorphism between $C^{\ast}$-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras

An elementary question: A $\ast$-preserving homomorphism between $C^{\ast}$-algebras is positive. Is there any condition that makes a positive homomorphism, $\ast$-preserving?

Comment: There is a long way to go from positivity-preserving to being a $*$-homomorphism. In decreasing order of generality: positive maps, $n$-positive maps (positivity preserving on $n \times n$ matrices), completely-positive maps ($n$-positive for all $n$), order-zero maps(CP and orthogonality preserving), *-homomorphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive homomorphism is automatically $\ast$-preserving. First note that any self-adjoint element can be written as the difference of two positive elements, so a positive homomorphism preserves self-adjoint elements. Next note that a homomorphism of complex algebras preserves $i$. Finally, note that an arbitrary element $a$ can be written

$$a = \frac{a + a^{\ast}}{2} + i \frac{a - a^{\ast}}{2i}$$

and a positive homomorphism preserves this decomposition. The adjoint is

$$a^{\ast} = \frac{a + a^{\ast}}{2} - i \frac{a - a^{\ast}}{2i}$$

so positive homomorphisms preserve adjoints.